# php - require, require_once, include - page loaded twice

Tags: php, require, require-once

I have a question.

I have file1.php in includes directory - so includes/file1.php
Another file is file2.php that have a

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/file1.php');
```

I've looked with firebug, and also I wrote something into a txt file, and seem

Comment: Could you please provide the code in both the files?

Comment: Can you show some code? This is very unclear.

Answer (score 3):

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/file1.php');
```

> The [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) statement is
>   identical to require() except PHP will
>   check if the file has already been
>   included, and if so, not include
>   (require) it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that a page is loaded twice in your client, i.e. in Firefox (or Firebug), you're code does most likely redirect or something like that.

It would be good to see a part of the code here, or at least what exactly you're seeing in Firebug (like HTTP actions / status codes).